# Cribbage two people , Run scoring Questions during the play

Tags: cribbage

alright during the play this is what went down ..

P1 - 4
P2 - 4
P1 - 3
P2 - 5
P1 - 6
P2 - 2
P1 - Go
P2 - 2

we are seeing 4 runs of 5 and two pairs.. are we losing it ?

Answer (score 1):

The final play (the 2 from P2) only scores a pair (plus the 1 for the Go). It doesn't see the whole 4-4-3-5-6-2-2 sequence as a double double run of five. Scoring in the play doesn't allow you to rearrange the cards to form new groups, so you can only score the last thing that was made, either a run or a tuple as the case may be (plus scoring the 15 if the play also brought the count to 15).

From the rules on the [wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_cribbage):

> During this phase of play run combinations cannot span a pair

So the play sequence you describe is scored as:

| Player | Play | Count | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 4 | 4 | - |
| P2 | 4 | 8 | 2 for the pair of 4's |
| P1 | 3 | 11 | - |
| P2 | 5 | 16 | 3 for the run 4-3-5 |
| P1 | 6 | 22 | 4 for the run 4-3-5-6 |
| P2 | 2 | 24 | 5 for the run 4-3-5-6-2 |
| P1 | Go | 24 | - |
| P2 | 2 | 26 | 2 for the pair of 2's |
| P2 | Go | Reset | P2 scores 1 for the Go |

Other portions of that wiki page give details:

> Card combinations cannot span a reset; once the total reaches 31 (or a Go has been scored) and counting has restarted at zero,

and

> During this phase of play run combinations cannot span a pair; in a play of 2, 3, 3, 4 the pair interrupts the run so only the pair is counted for points.

Also note there's no such thing as "double runs" in the play. Those only exist in the show as shorthand for the underlying combinations.